# Does "any solution x must satisfy $P(x)$ mean $\exists x $[x constitutes a solution to equation]$ \implies P(x)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I want to make sure that I am translating "any solution must satisfy $P(x)$" correctly into propositional logic. Is this $\exists x $[x constitutes a solution to equation]$ \implies P(x)$? I want to double check that I am correct to say that we are making an assumption that there exists a solution in "any solution must satisfy $P(x)$", and it doesn't matter if there is no solution to the equation in cotext, as our statement is just vacuously true.

Comment: As written $P(x)$ is bound by the existential quantifier. So what you wrote is: there exists $x$ such that if, $x$ is a solution, then $P(x)$.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect. Write $S(x)$ for "$x$ is a solution" (to some other equation, I assume). The correct interpretation of "any solution satisfies $P(x)$" is that *every* solution satisfies $P(x)$, which would be written

$$\forall x : S(x) \Rightarrow P(x).$$

The statement you've written, $\exists x : S(x) \Rightarrow P(x)$, does not mean what you think it means. It says that there exists an $x$ such that $S(x) \Rightarrow P(x)$. The statement $S(x) \Rightarrow P(x)$ is true if either $P(x)$ is true or $S(x)$ is false. So, this whole statement means that there exists an $x$ such that either $P(x)$ holds or $x$ is not a solution.